# Android battery consumption issue

Tags: android, performance, battery-saver

I have developed one android app which working well with all devices but with Galaxy S8 only consumed more battery compare to other devices.
How to can handle battery consumption for S8 ?
There are any tools by which i can get battery consumption details for my app.

Answer (score 0):

To get the details for battery consumption your app uses in any specific device is simple to see. Here is what You can follow-
To begin, head to your phone's main Settings menu, then tap the "Battery" entry. Just beneath the graph at the top of this screen, you'll find a list of the apps that have been draining your battery the most. If everything is going as it should, the top entry in this list should be "Screen."

Comment: Yes man,but at other devices battery consumption per hour is 0.2% and with Galaxy S8 it's show warning of battery consumption.